# migration from backendless 3 to backendless 4(swift code)

Tags: swift, backendless

[swift code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp2HU.png)

When I run the code shown in the picture above, it shows the following error:

> Value of type '[Any]' has no member 'data'

How can I fix this error? Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1. Please [edit] your question to include your code as text, not as an image. 2. Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+value+of+type+Any+has+no+member) before posting. This has been covered many times.

Comment: remove `data` part and try as `users.first`. It could work.

Comment: thanks adev, it works. Also thanks rmaddy to point out my mistakes.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New API returns `[Any]?` instead of `BackendlessCollection?`:

```
// v3
let withUser = users!.data.first as! BackendlessUser
// v4
let withUser = users!.first as! BackendlessUser
```

Complete migration guide: [Migration from 3.x to 4.x](https://backendless.com/docs/ios/doc.html#data_query)

> v3.0 = All SDK implementations use the BackendlessCollection class to represent a collection of data from the backend.
>
> v4.0 = BackendlessCollection is completely eliminated. Instead the backend returns an array of objects ([Any] in Swift)